# SuiteScript2.0 Please Add Value To Amount

Tags: javascript, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet that is creating an order. Most times this works but sometimes, maybe 1 in 50 it fails with this error. "Please enter a value for amount."

The error is thrown when sommitting this.

```
if(orderLine.amount){
    log.debug("itemrate", orderLine.itemrate);
    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId   : 'item',
        fieldId     : 'rate',
        value       : Number(orderLine.itemrate ? orderLine.itemrate : (orderLine.amount / orderLine.qty))
    });
    fieldServices.sleep(1000);
    log.debug("Amount", orderLine.amount);
    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId   : 'item',
        fieldId     : 'amount',
        value       : Number(orderLine.amount)
    });
}
```

The logs on a fail execution reads

```
2   View    Debug   Amount      26/05/2020  11:21 AM    -System-    118.0909090909091
3   View    Debug   itemrate    26/05/2020  11:21 AM    -System-    118.0909
```

So the amount is getting set with an amount but when I try to commit the line it doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: You should check if the `118.0909090909091` is a valid value for the `amount` field. Does it accept floats and if yes with how many significant digits. Maybe you should try to round it if it is meant to be an integer.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I added more logging to trying a determine if what you said was the problem and discovered the real problem.

Comment: Nice you've shorted this out. This kind of bugs are hard to track down. Do you care to offer the bountry?

Answer (score 0):

So here was the problem. I assumed the logging was on the line that I posted but it turned out it was trying to add another line with the amount of 0. JavaScript being JavaScript saw 0 as false in

```
 if(orderLine.amount)
```

so the amount was never added to the line. I changed this if statement to read

```
if(orderLine.amount || orderLine.amount == 0)
```

This solved the problem.